# How to get the count from a python dictionary made from Django querysets?

Tags: python, django, dictionary

these are the commands and outputs I am getting using my variables.

```
>>tags_list = list(tags_list)
>>print (tags_list)
[<Tag: Book needed>, <Tag: Book needed>, <Tag: Lab important>, <Tag: Easygoing>, <Tag: Book needed>, <Tag: Tough quizzes>, <Tag: Important lectures>, <Tag: Book needed>, <Tag: Tough quizzes>]
```

tags_list is a list made from joining Django query sets using itertools.chain.

```
>>tags = Counter(tags_list)
>>print (tags)
Counter({<Tag: Book needed>: 4, <Tag: Tough quizzes>: 2, <Tag: Important lectures>: 1, <Tag: Lab important>: 1, <Tag: Easygoing>: 1})
```

Now, I am using collections.Counter to count the queryset and turn it into a dictionary.

```
>>for tag in tags:
      >>print tag

Book needed
Tough quizzes
Important lectures
Lab important
Easygoing
```

So now I am printing the individual tags from my weird dictionary.
However, I want the outputs to be something like this

```
Book needed (4)
Tough quizzes (2)
Important lectures (1)
Lab important (1)
Easygoing (1)
```

How do I do this? I am not sure what the keys are in the dictionary, I mean they are django objects but I am not sure how I can access them. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counter acts like a normal dictionary; when you iterate it, it gives you the keys. If you want the values too, iterate over `.items()`:

```
for tag, count in tags.items():
      print "{} ({})".format(tag, count)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only printing the dict keys (tags), but you can also access the values (count):

```
for tag in tags:
    print tag, tags[tag]
```